# How to upload files to Amazon S3 using boto3 package when bucket name has a / delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3, bucket

I'm trying to upload a file to the Amazon S3 bucket that was set up by a provider. The problem is that the name of our bucket is 
--- /provider-folder/my-company-name ---
and I need to upload the following Key

/provider-folder/company-name/date/file-path

I've tried to use prefix and objects.filter to solve the delimiter issue but none of the combinations I've tried works.

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket_name = 'provider-folder'
prefix = 'company-name'
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix, delimiter = '/')

s3.meta.client.upload_file('file-path', 
                           objs, 'date/file-path')
```

I've also tried the following:

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket_name = 'company-name'
prefix = 'provider-folder/date'
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix, delimiter = '/')

s3.meta.client.upload_file('file-path', 
                           bucket, 'prefix/file-path')
```

And this too:

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket_name = 'provider-folder/company-name'
prefix = 'date'
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix, delimiter = '/')

s3.meta.client.upload_file('file-path', 
                           objs, 'file-path')
```

All return the same error

```
 220             'Invalid bucket name "%s": Bucket name must match '

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm now unsure what to pass as bucket name, prefix and key.

Comment: try adding an escape character "\". That is, bucket_name = 'provider-folder\/company-name' I haven't tested this but give it a try. thanks.

Comment: You can not have a forward slash (/) in a bucket name. What you describe I believe is not possible. Seems you may want to read up more on buckets, prefixes, and S3 objects.

Comment: I know that's the issue and have read extensively online about all the above without finding a clear answer, hence the question...